# AWS Amplify Auth Error in Angular project using pre-existing backend: "Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly."

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I'm in the process of trying to update a project I built in 2020 that no longer works but I keep running into this issue.

```
[ERROR] 04:09.562 AuthError - 
            Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. 
            The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
            This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:

            1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
                See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information

            2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js) for help upgrading Amplify packages.
```

I created a new angular (Ionic) project to see if I could pin-point the issue and again this issue has returned. I followed the documentation to set up amplify with the exception that we already have a backend so I ran `amplify pull --appId XXXXXX --envName XXXX` to get the **aws-exports.js**.

1. I've done `npm i aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-angular`
2. I've tried deleting **node-modules** and **package-lock.json**, and then running `npm i`
3. I've renamed **aws-exports.js** to **aws-exports.ts** and added it to my **ts-config.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
    "src/aws-exports.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

4. In **main.ts** I've added

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsmobile from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
Auth.configure(awsmobile); // I've tried both with and without this line
```

5. I've implemented the Authenticator UI Component as per the documentation.

Any information would be greatly appreciated! I've read through multiple threads on the issue and none of the advice has worked.

This is the contents of my **aws-exports.ts** (with data redacted!)

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "eu-west-2",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://XXXXX.appsync-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "eu-west-2",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "XXXXX",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "eu-west-2:XXXXX",
    "aws_cognito_region": "eu-west-2",
    "oauth": {},
    "aws_cognito_username_attributes": [],
    "aws_cognito_social_providers": [],
    "aws_cognito_signup_attributes": [],
    "aws_cognito_mfa_types": [],
    "aws_cognito_password_protection_settings": {
        "passwordPolicyCharacters": []
    },
    "aws_cognito_verification_mechanisms": [],
    "aws_mobile_analytics_app_id": "XXXXX",
    "aws_mobile_analytics_app_region": "eu-west-1"
};

export default awsmobile;
```

**Edit:**
I've also tried running `amplify init` and creating a new Amplify project but the issue persists. I did run `amplify push`

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "XXXX",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^2.0.11",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.4.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.7",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.4.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

**Edit:**
As suggested by Juicy-g, I've tried using

```
"@aws-amplify/auth": "^4.3.14", 
"@aws-amplify/core": "^4.3.14"
```

with

```
import { Amplify } from '@aws-amplify/core'; 
import { Auth } from '@aws-amplify/auth'; 
import awsmobile from './aws-exports'; 
Amplify.configure(awsmobile); 
Auth.configure(awsmobile);
```

and I'm still getting the same result. The latest version of @aws-amplify/auth seems to have an internal issue so I matched the latest version of @aws-amplify/core

Comment: Have you tried `import { Amplify } from '@aws-amplify/core'` and `import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth'`? It worked for one of my projects last year, but i can’t remember exactly why I was having problems.

Comment: Just tried using
```
"@aws-amplify/auth": "^4.3.14",
    "@aws-amplify/core": "^4.3.14"
```
with

```
import { Amplify } from '@aws-amplify/core';
import { Auth } from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import awsmobile from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
Auth.configure(awsmobile);
```
and I had the same result. The latest version of @aws-amplify/auth seems to have an internal issue so I matched the latest version of @aws-amplify/core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, this is due to us having to migrate our project over from our old Amplify project due to it ending up in an unrecoverable state. It didn't connect correctly to our cognito user pools and so all the needed information wasn't being provided in `aws-exports.js`

I'm not quite sure why it wasn't working with a new project and a new amplify project but it's working now.

I was missing the `aws_user_pools_id` and the `aws_user_pools_web_client_id` fields. Providing them manually resolved the issue.